# Архитектура кода, как правильно оформить или сократить код?

Tags: java, android, архитектура

Я новичок в Android, осваиваю сама. Вопрос в следующем:

У меня приложение берет курсы валют с API сайта. Я так же добавляю Swipe on Refresh  и получается что в методе `onRefresh()` дублирую код из `onCreate`.

Как правильно сделать так, что бы код не дублировать? Или это нормально что один и тот же код встречается в основном коде и в методе?

Хочется понимать как это делают настоящие профессионалы и как правильно оформить. Поправьте пожалуйста мой код, или скиньте примеры как надо делать или где посмотреть.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    public String dollar = " ";
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    public String evro = " ";
    private String MY_LOG = "my_log";
    public TextView tvDollar, tvEvro;
    public static final String BASE_URL = https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvDollar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDollar);
        tvEvro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEvro);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        GetRates getRates = retrofit.create(GetRates.class);
        Call<PojoUSD> callUSD = getRates.getCurrency("USD");
        callUSD.enqueue(new Callback<PojoUSD>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PojoUSD> call, Response<PojoUSD> response) {
                PojoUSD info = response.body();
                Double dol  = info.getRates().getRUB();
                dollar = String.format("%.4g", dol);
                tvDollar.setText(dollar);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PojoUSD> call, Throwable t) {


            }
        });

        Call<PojoUSD> callEUR = getRates.getCurrency("EUR");
        callEUR.enqueue(new Callback<PojoUSD>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PojoUSD> call, Response<PojoUSD> response) {
                PojoUSD info = response.body();

                Double ev  = info.getRates().getRUB();
                evro = String.format("%.4g", ev);
                tvEvro.setText(evro);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PojoUSD> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Отменяем анимацию обновления
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        GetRates getRates = retrofit.create(GetRates.class);
        Call<PojoUSD> callUSD = getRates.getCurrency("USD");
        callUSD.enqueue(new Callback<PojoUSD>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PojoUSD> call, Response<PojoUSD> response) {
                PojoUSD info = response.body();
                Double dol  = info.getRates().getRUB();
                dollar = String.format("%.4g", dol);
                tvDollar.setText(dollar);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PojoUSD> call, Throwable t) {


            }
        });

        Call<PojoUSD> callEUR = getRates.getCurrency("EUR");
        callEUR.enqueue(new Callback<PojoUSD>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PojoUSD> call, Response<PojoUSD> response) {
                PojoUSD info = response.body();
                Double ev  = info.getRates().getRUB();
                evro = String.format("%.4g", ev);
                tvEvro.setText(evro);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PojoUSD> call, Throwable t) {              }
        });
            }     }, 4000);

    }

    public interface GetRates {
        @GET("latest")
        Call<PojoUSD> getCurrency(@Query("base") String currency);
        //@GET("latest")
        //Call<List<PojoUSD>> getCurrencyList (@Query("base") String currency);
    }


}
```

Comment: Если хочется понять как писать чистый код, то советую почитать Совершенный Код - Стив Макконелл и Чистый Код - Дядюшки Боба)

Comment: Знаю и в процессе чтения) Спасибо! С теорией все вроде ясно, а как на практике сталкиваюсь, сразу сложности, ответ ниже очень помог, буду разбираться и учиться ))

Comment: Если кусок кода повторяется - его стоит вынести в отдельный метод.

Comment: Совершенный код Макконела штука хорошая. Как впрочем и остальные книги на эту тему. Но как по мне, то 800+ страниц- это слишком. Какое бы качество этой книги не было бы - она должна быть юзабельна, Юзать повседневно такой талмуд - нереально. К тому же там много того, что в жизни разработчика встретится ровно никогда раз. Понять же что нужно а что нет - сложно, так как это покажет только опыт. Я для себя сначала нашел смысл следовать принципам SOLID, потом нашел интересную инфу в:  https://www.fer.unizg.hr/_download/repository/ProjectConventions_-_Java_Android.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Где об этом почитать... не могу сказать. Просто смотрите, что у вас дублируется и выносите в отдельный `private метод`. Если у вас одинаковые части ничего не возвращают, то просто используете в новом методе всё общее. Если что-то должно вернуться, тогда сначала объявляете в вашем `public` методе переменную и приравниваете новый `private` метод к это переменной, например, так

```
public void one(){
    MyObjec object = method();
}

private MyObject method(){
    MyObject newObject=new MyObject();
    newObject.setId(1);
    return  newObject;
}



 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myMethod();                                          
        tvDollar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDollar);
        tvEvro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEvro);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    }

        public void onRefresh() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Отменяем анимацию обновления
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);                                                 
        myMethod();} 
        }, 4000);
       }


    private void myMethod(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        GetRates getRates = retrofit.create(GetRates.class);
        Call<PojoUSD> callUSD = getRates.getCurrency("USD");
        callUSD.enqueue(new Callback<PojoUSD>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PojoUSD> call, Response<PojoUSD> response) {
                onResponseDo(call,response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PojoUSD> call, Throwable t) {}
        });

         Call<PojoUSD> callEUR = getRates.getCurrency("EUR");
         callEUR.enqueue(new Callback<PojoUSD>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<PojoUSD> call, Response<PojoUSD> response) {
         onResponseDo(call,response);
         }
         @Override
         public void onFailure(Call<PojoUSD> call, Throwable t) {}               
        });
        }

    private void onResponseDo(Call<PojoUSD> call, Response<PojoUSD> response){
         PojoUSD info = response.body();
         Double ev  = info.getRates().getRUB();
         evro = String.format("%.4g", ev);
         tvEvro.setText(evro);
    }
```

Конечно, это не очень хорошо, что код дублируется, но иногда этого не избежать, по причине того, что код абсолютно одинаковый, но вызывается с разными параметрами, которых порой может быть очень много для объявления того или иного объекта. В таких случаях сложно выделить общий участок. Наверное, проще будет переписать целиком метод, чтобы избежать этих повторов, но в случае, если это ваш код и это можно реализовать.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую исправить как вы советуете. Похожие ситуации встречаются часто. Хотелось бы уметь сокращать :)

Comment: @KateSh Можно использовать Notepad++, Может быть ваша среда разработки тоже видит дубли кода и подскажет, что можно убрать

Comment: я использую андроид студию, и ее все устраивает. с примерно понимаю о чем вы говорите, буду пробовать реализовать.

Comment: вот смотрите у меня в методе OnRespose есть часть где:
PojoUSD info = response.body(); 
и этот response вызывается в методе Call, это запрос на сайт, я не понимаю как его можно вынести в отдельный метод. а все остальное в этом методе завязано на ответе на этот response. 
Это значит что в моем случае сократить код никак не получится? или я что-то не понимаю? 
Спасибо

Comment: так у меня в примере уже ведь это вынесено в отдельный `private onResponseDo()` метод

Comment: да, извините, пыталась сама по памяти писать, не копируя и недоглядела.

Comment: @KateSh, не страшно) Если вас ответ устраивает, отметьте его как принятый либо сообщите, как бы я мог его исправить/дополнить.

Comment: @KateSh одну строчку кода нет никакого смысла выносить в отдельный метод хотя бы потому, что это так же будет одна строчка кода .. да и вызов такого метода обойдется "дороже", чем прямой вызов запроса.

Comment: @pavlofff, тут целых 4 строчки в методе. Или вы про какую?

Comment: @KateSh про [четвертый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/971531/%d0%90%d1%80%d1%85%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-java-android/971535?noredirect=1#comment1630562_971535) комментарий

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код можно и нужно дорабоать.
Сделаем следующее - в каждом запросе изменяется только название валюты, остальной код дублируется. Поэтому сделаем метод `getCurrency()`, который будет принимать это название и возвращать значение данной валюты и метод `updateUI()` который будет обновлять информацию в виджете через ассоциативную карту, когда данные будут получены:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    private String MY_LOG = "my_log";
    public TextView tvDollar, tvEvro;
    Map<String, TextView> states = new HashMap();
    Retrofit retrofit;
    GetRates getRates;
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvDollar = findViewById(R.id.tvDollar);
        tvEvro = findViewById(R.id.tvEvro);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        // Создаем асоциативный массив для обновления виджетов по названию валюты
        states.put("USD",tvDollar);
        states.put("EUR",tvEvro);

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        getRates = retrofit.create(GetRates.class);

        getCurrency("USD");
        getCurrency("EUR");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Отменяем анимацию обновления
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                getCurrency("USD");
                getCurrency("EUR");
            }     }, 4000);

    }

    public interface GetRates {
        @GET("latest")
        Call<PojoUSD> getCurrency(@Query("base") String currency);
        //@GET("latest")
        //Call<List<PojoUSD>> getCurrencyList (@Query("base") String currency);
    }

    private void updateUI(String cur, String currency){

        // обновляем виджет по названию валюты
        states.get(cur).setText(currency);
    }

    private void getCurrency(final String cur) {
        Call<PojoUSD> call = getRates.getCurrency(cur);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<PojoUSD>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PojoUSD> call, Response<PojoUSD> response) {
                PojoUSD info = response.body();

                Double ev = info.getRates().getRUB();
                String currency = String.format("%.4g", ev);
                updateUI(cur,currency);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PojoUSD> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Классы, которые создают один и тот же экземпляр лучше выносить в поле класса и инициализировать однажды. Здесь это класс `retrofit` и `getRates`, каждый их экземпляр ничем не отличается от предыдущего, не принимает новых параметров и тд, теперь они создаются при создании активити и затем используются везде, где это необходимо. В противном случае у вас при каждом свайпе будет создаваться один и тот же экземпляр, дублирующий уже имеющийся и занимающий память (обращаться с каждым новым свайпом будет уже к новому экземпляру, а созданный до этого будет "забыт" и лежать без дела, занимая память и дожидаясь сборщика мусора)
Примечание: конкретно с ретрофитом я работал мало и, возможно, в его случае и нужно создавать отдельные дублирующие экземпляры. Здесь указана общая концепция.

Здесь мы не выносим весь код в один метод без параметров (как в другом ответе), так как это непрактично с точки зрения дальнейшей поддержки и вообще архитектуры в целом (метод должен выполнять одну простую операцию). С таким подходом мы всегда можем получить значение любой валюты отдельно, если это вдруг понадобится в будущем или просто добавлять новые и удалять ненужные. В идеале все это должно делаться вообще в другом классе (который будет получать из активити требования на курс определенной валюты и возвращать ее значение), а не в активити.

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы вам вообще не сделать все раздельно. Это упростит написание кода и дальнейшее его расширение.

Касаемо `Retrofit` можно сделать по такой схеме: 
Вынести инициализацию на уровне класса Application, 
вынести `Retrofit` в отдельный класс, 
интерфейс в отдельный класс. 
В активности оставить только реализацию. По началу может показаться сложнее, но по факту работать удобнее.